# strccat function protptype in c programing

Tags: c

I have a question about this function prototype in C programming

```
char *strncat( char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n )
```

why the first parameter is not const but the second parameter is const?

```
int main(void)
{
    char *nameOne; 
    char nameTwo[11];
    char *pName = nameTwo;
    nameOne = "Moe Howard";

    strcpy(pName, "Larry Fine");

    strcat(nameOne,"shirin");
    printf("%s",nameOne);

    return 0;
}
```

it does not work 
any hint ?

Comment: The first parameter gets modified, while the second one doesn't need to be changed, only read from.

Comment: nameOne content is stored in read-only memory location, so you can't basicly modify it

Answer (score 2):

Because strncat needs to write into the character buffer that (s1) is pointing to; but it only needs to read from the character buffer that (s2) is pointing to.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have added some lines of codes that follow your guide, but for some reasons the program stopped working. any Idea?

Comment: You can only `strncat` onto the end of a string which is an an area of allocated memory big enough for the resulting string.

Answer (score 2):

People often mistake what

```
const char *s2;
```

actually means. It a *non-constant pointer* to *constant characters*. That means you're not permitted to change the actual characters "behind" the pointer, though you can move the pointer itself to wherever you want (`const char * const xyzzy;` locks both the characters *and* the pointer to unchanging values, and `char * const xyzzy;` will lock the pointer but allow you to change the characters it points to).

That's why the first argument is `char *` - the act of concatenating another (source) string to it means that you have to change the underlying characters of the destination string.

Because you don't need to modify the source string at all, it can be `const`.

And the reason your code as posted doesn't work lies here:

```
nameOne = "Moe Howard";
:
strcat (nameOne, "shirin");
```

You are not permitted to modify string literals, of which `nameOne` points to (well, it *may* work but it's not guaranteed to). This is specifically pointed out in `C11 6.4.5 String literals /7` where it talks about the character arrays that C strings consist of:

> It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the
>   appropriate values. If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
>   undefined.

The reason this is as it is is mainly due to compilers that optimise string literals. For example, the code:

```
char *s1 = "defined";
char *s2 = "undefined";
```

may result in the following memory layout, with both variables "sharing" the underlying data:

```
          +------------------------------ s1
          |
          v
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
| u | n | d | e | f | i | n | e | d | \0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
  ^
  |
  +-------------------------------------- s2
```